# How to make the child table's columns have the same width as it's parent table columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table within a table (inside a td).

This child table has exactly the same number of columns as the parent table.

The only problem is, the child table's columns aren't the same width as the parent table's columns.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

How should I style the child table?

Is there a predefined way to fix this?

Or do I need to write a "normalization" function via jquery which will change the width of columns on page load?

Comment: use proper colspan and it should work, assuming that you have nothing to change in css , as you havent tagged this question as css

Comment: I did colspan = 15 on the td. (parent has 15 columns), if that's what you meant. But still looks like this.

Comment: okay, you need to make sure width is set properly. then you can leverage css text-ellipsis property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function normaliseWidth(id)
{
    iter = 1;
    $("#splitForm" + id + " td").each(function() {
        //alert($(this)); 
        $(this).width($("#" + id + " td:nth-child(" + iter + ")").width());
        ++iter;
    });
}
```

I just iterated through all the td's and changed their width to parent's width.

This seems to have fixed it. I'm hoping there won't be any side effects to this. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create another table if they have the same number of columns. You should just add a row instead of another table. That way your column will be the same.

The problem is the content of your inner table is pushing cells width.

Comment: I have my reasons - in this case it's because I need to surround the row with a form. And if you surround a row with a form - that's invalid HTML, so I need a whole table inside the td. And thats just one of the reasons - this is a part of the datatables plugins which work this way - they add a new table below the row upon click.

Comment: In that case make sure the width of the parent table columns is base of the width of the one inside it. So adjust the width of the columns of the inner table to fit there content width and then adjust the parent ones.

Comment: Can you edit your post and elaborate further? I'm not sure how to do what you described.

Comment: Adjust the witdh of each cell of the table with the gray background to make sure that the content in it have enough space. So all the cell of your gray table will have a fixed width an then you put the same width to your parent table cells. The principe is to make sure that the cells width is set buy you and not by the content in it.

Comment: Ex.: If you have a field of 125px width in one cell, make the cell 140 to make sure it fit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a couple different things.

the fastest way would be to add classes to each column (and make sure they pair up between parent/child). I usually use a "col-" prefix. Set your widths to the classes and you should be a lot closer.

Also be sure to remove any borders, paddings, margins, etc. if it still isnt quite right look into [border-collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to do it that way, either specify the width of each column explicitly using CSS or the HTML attribute in both tables.

You could also write javascript code that happens after the page is loaded to adjust the size of the columns of that top table to match the bottom table.  You're mileage may vary with this approach.

Your comment in another answer about needing a form for each row makes me think you could modify your layout to put the form around the table and combine the two tables to have the header and data rows in the same table. Then make some backend code changes to handle the posts differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of the `rowspan` attribute rather than nesting tables. If you need, say 3 sets of data, but want them all to have the same heading (on the left side) set the row span of that left cell to 3, and leave each of the others with the default of 1. You'll need to neglect adding that cell for the subsequent rows.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp